# Problem with .psd transparent picture impression in Indesign

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign

when i am printing my Indesign document with .psd (photoshop) pictures with transparent background, there is always a white background ! i do not see it on screen but when i am printing all pictures have a white background. Can anyone help me with this please.

thanks

Comment: why someone give a -1 to my question but not helping or answering ? i have this problem for a while and can not find help to resolve it, and dont seems to be here, tks

Comment: after many test it seems to be color profile between indesign and the printer. Anyone had this problem before ?

Comment: I bet quite many of us have at least thought that maybe you have accidentally used white paper.  But obviously you are not here to read bad jokes. Unfortunately none of us know anything about the 500 possible settings of your software - only guessing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the image as a PNG file, instead of psd. Save your psd if you want to re work the file later on, but saving a copy as png will always remain transparent. DONT flatten your image, if you do that it will save with a white background. Just save it as you would a psd file, only select png instead. Cheers.

Comment: thank have tried that many times, and still have white square, not on screen but when printing ;/

Comment: If you are printing on white paper, of course you are going to have a white background. If you are printing on transparent paper, or clear plastic and the background is still white, i am not sure what to advise.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the transparent area isn’t completely transparent.

If possible please upload a sample somewhere and give us the link so someone could inspect it.

Comment: 2018 question `:)` chances are it's been solved by now

Comment: @Scott lol yeah. I just forgot to check the date.